# Pass variable with spaces into array

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm parsing a HTML page with a bash script and extracting (with `grep` and `sed`)

```
    string number one
    string number two
    string number three
    etc
```

as `$str` in a parsing loop followed by

```
    array+=($str)
```

When the array is printed with

```
    for each in "${array[@]}"
    do
        echo "$each"
    done
```

I end up with

```
    string
    number
    one
    string
    number
    ....
```

Clearly spaces are being used as a delimiter when adding a new element in the array, but I can't seem to work out how to pass the entire string as an element!

Comment: Unquoted parameter expansions are wrong until proven otherwise.

Comment: I found your comment hilarious and very important to commit to memory @chepner, thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid splitting each element of the array on whitespace, you should double quote your variable:

```
array+=("$str")
```

Comment: I was certain I had tested quotation marks in testing, apparently not. Thanks for the help!